# How to load multiple images from JSON and display in gallery view in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-volley, android-image, android-gallery

I am developing an application with Gallery option. I have some set of URL's in `JSON`. I already parse it and saved in String `ArrayList`. Now I just want to display those images in `GalleryView`. I have gone through various references which are not helpful. I have used `UniversalImageLoader` as well, It worked for one URL only.I need to load multiple URL's which is present in my `ArrayList`.  Kindly give me some tips to achieve it.

**UPDATED**

This is my Gallery Activity class

```
public class Gallery extends AppCompatActivity {
public ArrayList<GalleryItem> imageURL;
private ImageView selectedImageView;
ArrayList<Drawable> dataDraw= new ArrayList<>();
private GridView mGridView;
public Gallery gallery;

private GalleryImageAdapter galImageAdapter;

public String url="my_url";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);
    mGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.galleryGrid);
    imageURL=new ArrayList<>();



    new AsyncHttpTaskforGallery().execute(url);
//        galImageAdapter = new GalleryImageAdapter(this, dataDraw);
    galImageAdapter=new GalleryImageAdapter(this,R.layout.gallery_item,imageURL);
    mGridView.setAdapter(galImageAdapter);


}



public class AsyncHttpTaskforGallery extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

    @Override

    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {

        Integer result = 0;

        try {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(params[0]));
            int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();


            if (statusCode == 200) {

                String response = streamToString(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent());
                parseResult(response);
                result = 1;
            }
            else {
                result = 0;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.d("TAG", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {


        if (result == 1) {
            galImageAdapter.setGridData(imageURL);
        }

        else {

        }


    }
}


String streamToString(InputStream stream) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    String line;
    String result = "";

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

        result += line;
    }


    if (null != stream) {

        stream.close();
    }

    return result;
}


private void parseResult(String result) {

    try {

        JSONArray posts = new JSONArray(result);

        GalleryItem galleryItem;
        for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject post = posts.optJSONObject(i);
            String path = post.optString("path");
            String newText=path.replace("\\", "/");
            String image="http://***/"+newText;
            Log.e("imageURL", image);
            galleryItem=new GalleryItem();
            galleryItem.setImage(image);
            imageURL.add(galleryItem);

        }

    }

    catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
  }
```

**GalleryAdapter**

```
public class GalleryImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GalleryItem> {

private Context mContext;
private int layoutResourceId;
private ArrayList<GalleryItem> mGalleryData = new ArrayList<GalleryItem>();
public GalleryImageAdapter(Context mContext, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<GalleryItem> mGalleryData) {
    super(mContext, layoutResourceId, mGalleryData);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mGalleryData = mGalleryData;
}
public void setGridData(ArrayList<GalleryItem> mGalleryData) {
    this.mGalleryData = mGalleryData;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.IMVgallery);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
         holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    GalleryItem item = mGalleryData.get(position);

    Picasso.with(mContext).load(item.getImage()).into(holder.imageView);
    return row;
}
static class ViewHolder {

    ImageView imageView;
}

}
```

Displaying Images in gridview is not looking good. I need to display in galleryview and on clicking the image, it should expand.

Comment: try picasoo image for android

Comment: okay... If I use picasoo, will it be scrollable? Like swiping right,left?

Comment: Picasoo or glide will allow to load images async. it has nothing to do with swipe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GalleryView -> Use a RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager

Then in your RecyclerView Adapter's ViewHolder initialisation, load the image in to the respective ImageView using Picasso library.

Now what happens in when a User clicks on individual images? Are you planning to open it in a full screen view?

If yes, use ViewPager for the same. Again use the similar technique. Use Picasso to load image in the respective ImageView in your ViewPager adapter.

For picasso library, refer to:
http://square.github.io/picasso/

Let me know if you need more help with this.

**UPDATE**:

1. Try to find out how to implement a RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager
2. Your recyclerview item view should have an imageview in it, which you will populate with the image using Picasoo library in ViewHolder's initialisation.
3. In onClick of ImageView -> Open another activity with the same set of URIs and use these URIs to populate the ViewPager with these images.

**UPDATE 2**:

Lets say, your Gallery's Adapter is "MyAdapter". It should something like this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> mUrls;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> urls) {
        mContext = context;
        mUrls = urls;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_gallery_item_layout, null);
        MyViewHolder rcv = new MyViewHolder(layoutView);
        return rcv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(mUrls.get(position)).into(holder.mImageView);
        //Do something here
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUrls.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private final ImageView mImageView;
        //Other views

        public MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gallery_item_imageview);
            mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view){
                    //This is were the magic happens:
                    //We are opening the full image viewer activity that contains a ViewPager to show the images
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MyFullViewActivity.class);
                    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("urls", mUrls);
                    intent.putInt("starting_index", getPosition());
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }

            });
            //Initialize other views here

        }
    }
}
```

Note that in ImageView's onCLick, we will start another activity "MyFullViewActivity", this activity has a ViewPager with an imageview in the item layout. We are also passing two intent extras to this activity:

1. "urls" : This is the list of urls that will be used by the ViewPager
2. "starting_index" : It will tell the activity to start at the index provided in this value. i.e. If user clciks on 2nd image in your gallery, the MyFullViewActivity should start with that index, rather than starting with the first index everytime.

Now you can implement a ViewPagerAdapter and change the images accordingly (using Picasso as described in the above example).

Let me know in case you need more help with this.

**UPDATE 3:**

Here is how you initialize the recyclerview:

```
RecyclerView mGalleryViewRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.my_gallery_recycler_view);
GridLayoutManager mGridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(mContext, 2); // here 2 indicates the number of columns in each row.
mGalleryViewRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGridLayoutManager);
```

Comment: I'm leaving for my home right now. Will upload a sample code snippet later in the night. Meanwhile try exploring the idea I've suggested. 
I've updated my answers with some more pointers.

Comment: Hey Anish, I've updated my answer with a small example. Please go through it and let me know in case you have any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using picasso and adapter as:
Grid adapter:

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<String> list;
public ListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> posters){
    this.mContext = context;
    this.list = posters;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view=null;
    ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(posters.get(position)).into(imageView);
    return view;
}
}
```

In your list_item.xml define your image view properties and in main activity set this adapter to your grid view and pass list of url's.

Comment: I did so. But It looks like grid images. Not like galleryview.  Anyway thanks for your code. But I am looking for more optimistic one